# What is equivalent of CodeIgniter's $this->load->vars() in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter-3

In CodeIgniter I use `$this->load->vars()` to pass an array of data along with the loading of view. In my target view, I use `$this->load->get_var()` to get that array and then the array is used to fill up the dropdown menu and so on.

Now I am new in Laravel. In one of my recent Laravel project I need to do the same task (I mean I need to pass one or more array of data along with the view to initialize some dropdown). But I don't know how to pass data along with the view page in Laravel and how to get the array from view page.

Comment: Was there anything in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views) that you were having trouble with in particular?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the documentation. It is well documented and information related Laravel is easily available on many platforms.

By the way, for passing data to view you have to return view in your controller along with data like below:

```php
$dropdown = array(1,2,3,4);

return view('home',compact('drowdown'))
```

now in `view(home)` you can use it directly:

```php
// home.blade.php

@foreach($drowdown as $key)
    {{$key}}
@endforecah
```

Comment: While this works, I prefer the clearer `return view('name.of.view')->with('name_of_variable', $variable);` syntax to `compact()`. More understandable for a newbie to the framework.

Comment: `comapct` it's just a array function if see php documentation. you can mark this answer  for others user if someone have related query

Comment: I know that, and you know that, but the Laravel docs use `with()` and not `compact()` for good reason - it's a somewhat confusing method for newbies.